# JavaScript & submit form & Enter & set focus to next element

Tags: javascript, submit, enter, setfocus, submit-button

I'm trying to create a simple submit form in WYSIWYG Web Designer 10 but I have a BIG problem with Enter key. There are several edit boxes on the form and I'd like to have the following functionality (via JavaScript):
1. Enter key on an Edit Box should not submit the form.
2. Enter key on an Edit Box should set focus to the following element (edit box or a submit button). Submit button is the last element in tabIndex order.
3. To submit the form user must:
  either click the submit button,
  or press Enter when the submit button has the focus.
**4. Must work in any browser.**

This is a snippet that works quite good (it sets focus to the next element):

```js
      var elem = document.activeElement;
   
       var tidx  = +(elem.getAttribute('tabindex')) +1,
           elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

       for (var i=elems.length; i--;) 
          {
           var tidx2 = elems[i].getAttribute('tabindex');
           if (tidx2 == tidx) elems[i].focus();
          }
```

The only problem I have is Enter key (keyCode) validation which should precede the code to change focus. I have been testing in FF 32, PaleMoon 25 (FF clone), Chrome 38 & IE 10.

Thank you very much for your time in advance.

P.S. I'm a newbie in JavaScript. I use to work with MS Access where similar problem would be solved within two minutes.
I have spent several hours on this simple task but no luck. I have tried many examples that I've found on the web (incl. stackoverflow.com). As to **event** handling (where I'm trying to test the keyCode) various browsers behave differently.

Comment: What's wrong with using the TAB key to move to the next field?

Comment: You realise that taking this approach undermines the established user-interface, with which your users are already familiar, of HTML forms? Unless you're clearly sign-posting this implementation *and* the users have asked for it, consider not doing it. Incidentally, you really need to add HTML to your snippet to make that code meaningful in any way.

Comment: @Weather Vane: Users keep pressing Enter instead of Tab.

Comment: @David Thomas: Yes, I'd like to change the behavior of the form. It's not only me - there are many threads discussing the same problem. Ie. there should be a tool to change Enter behavior... just to replace 13 by 9.

Comment: After some exploration: Firefox & PaleMoon can't handle event. Chrome, IE, Opera & Safari work fine. How can I handle events in Firefox & it's clones?

Comment: I have a solution: `function fncNextCtl(e)
// e = event
{
   if (e.keyCode == 13)
   {
      var elem = document.activeElement;
   
      var tidx  = +(elem.getAttribute('tabindex')) +1,
          elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

      for (var i=elems.length; i--;) 
      {
         var tidx2 = elems[i].getAttribute('tabindex');
         if (tidx2 == tidx) elems[i].focus();
      }

      e.keyCode = 9;
      return false;
     }

     else

     {
        return true;
     }
}` WWB10 onkeydown: `return fncNextCtl(event);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried and mixed a lot of found in web and created this one.
So far it's working for me... just give it a try

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input, select, checkbox, radio, button', function (e) {
    return focusNextOnEnter(e, this);
})
```

and the function somewhere in your JS file.

```
 function focusNextOnEnter(e, selector) {
    var longSelector = 'input:visible:enabled:not([readonly="readonly"]), textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly="readonly"]), select:visible:enabled, button:visible:enabled';
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if ($(selector).is(':not(textarea)')  // it's not a textarea - enter in text area
            && keyCode === 13 // it's enter key
            && !($(selector).attr('id') === 'submitButton')) // it's not submitButton, save-on-enter here
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(longSelector)[$(longSelector).index($(selector)) + 1].focus();
        return true;
    }
}
```

instead of the last check

```
$(selector).attr('id') === 'submitButton'
```

you can always check

```
$(selector).is('[type="submit"]')
```

this will hopefully return what you are looking for i.e. submit on enter on submit button